# Spring Autowired "Not a managed type"

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, autowired

I have this problem with Spring. I cannot understand what does not go.
Should be a problem with the autowired attribute, I have also consulted other guides on the site but have not been successful.

[image: this is structure]

**Console error**

> ```
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
> AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Trenitalia2' did not find a matching property.
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Server built:          Jun 21 2017 09:44:18 UTC
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Server number:         9.0.0.0
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: OS Name:               Windows 10
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: OS Version:            10.0
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Architecture:          amd64
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Luca\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat999
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Luca\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat999
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Luca\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat999\endorsed
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
> INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.]
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
> INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
> INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
> INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
> INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
> INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 428 ms
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
> INFORMAZIONI: Starting service [Catalina]
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
> INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:14 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
> INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
> INFORMAZIONI: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
> ago 19, 2017 6:25:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
> INFORMAZIONI: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
> INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
> INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Aug 19 18:25:14 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
> INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
> INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]
> INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
> ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abilitazioneService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private it.uniroma3.repository.AbilitazioneRepository it.uniroma3.service.AbilitazioneService.abilitazioneRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abilitazioneRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class it.uniroma3.model.Abilitazione
> ```

**DBWEBCONFIG**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("it.uniroma3")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("it.uniroma3.repository")
public class DBWebConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());






        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename(env.getRequiredProperty("message.source.basename"));
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }

}
```

**APPLICATIONCONTEXT.XML**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="it.uniroma3">
            <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
        </context:component-scan>


         <import resource="security.xml"/>

    </beans>
```

**APPLICATION.PROPERTIES**

```
message.source.basename=i18n/messages


db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/trenitalia
db.username=postgres
db.password=postgres

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=it.uniroma3.model 
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
it.uniroma3.model.Abilitazione ,
```

For a better understanding I added the template, repository and associated services, I hope I can be as understandable as possible

```
package it.uniroma3.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.jboss.logging.Message;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat;

@Entity
public class Abilitazione {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Size(min=1, message="Non è un nome valido")
    private String nomeAbilitazione;
    @Size(min=3, message="Non è un link valido")
    private String linkAllegato;
    @Size(max=1, message="Non è uno stato valido")
    private String info;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    @Max(31)
    private Integer giornoScadenza;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    @Max(12)
    private Integer meseScadenza;

    @NotNull
    @Min(2000)
    @Max(2100)
    private Integer annoScadenza;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    @Max(31)
    private Integer giornoConseguimento;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    @Max(12)
    private Integer meseConseguimento;

    @NotNull
    @Min(2000)
    @Max(2100)
    private Integer annoConseguimento;

    private LocalDate dataLocale;
    private LocalDate dataScadenzaAbilitazioneTot;
    private LocalDate dataConseguimentoAbilitazioneTot;



    @ManyToOne
    private Dipendente dipendente;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNomeAbilitazione() {
        return nomeAbilitazione;
    }

    public void setNomeAbilitazione(String nomeAbilitazione) {
        this.nomeAbilitazione = nomeAbilitazione;
    }

    public String getLinkAllegato() {
        return linkAllegato;
    }

    public void setLinkAllegato(String linkAllegato) {
        this.linkAllegato = linkAllegato;
    }

    public Dipendente getDipendente() {
        return dipendente;
    }

    public void setDipendente(Dipendente dipendente) {
        this.dipendente = dipendente;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public LocalDate getDataLocale() {
        this.dataLocale = LocalDate.now();
        return dataLocale;
    }

    public void setDataLocale(LocalDate dataLocale) {
        this.dataLocale = dataLocale;
    }

    public Integer getGiornoScadenza() {
        return giornoScadenza;
    }

    public void setGiornoScadenza(Integer giornoScadenza) {
        this.giornoScadenza = giornoScadenza;
    }

    public Integer getMeseScadenza() {
        return meseScadenza;
    }

    public Integer getAnnoConseguimento() {
        return annoConseguimento;
    }

    public Integer getGiornoConseguimento() {
        return giornoConseguimento;
    }

    public Integer getMeseConseguimento() {
        return meseConseguimento;
    }

    public void setAnnoConseguimento(Integer annoConseguimento) {
        this.annoConseguimento = annoConseguimento;
    }

    public void setGiornoConseguimento(Integer giornoConseguimento) {
        this.giornoConseguimento = giornoConseguimento;
    }

    public void setMeseConseguimento(Integer meseConseguimento) {
        this.meseConseguimento = meseConseguimento;
    }

    public void setMeseScadenza(Integer meseScadenza) {
        this.meseScadenza = meseScadenza;
    }

    public Integer getAnnoScadenza() {
        return annoScadenza;
    }

    public void setAnnoScadenza(Integer annoScadenza) {
        this.annoScadenza = annoScadenza;
    }

    public LocalDate getDataConseguimentoAbilitazioneTot() {
        return dataConseguimentoAbilitazioneTot;
    }

    public void setDataConseguimentoAbilitazioneTot(LocalDate dataConseguimentoAbilitazioneTot) {
        this.dataConseguimentoAbilitazioneTot = dataConseguimentoAbilitazioneTot;
    }

    public LocalDate getDataScadenzaAbilitazioneTot() {
        return dataScadenzaAbilitazioneTot;
    }

    public void setDataScadenzaAbilitazioneTot(LocalDate dataScadenzaAbilitazioneTot) {
        this.dataScadenzaAbilitazioneTot = dataScadenzaAbilitazioneTot;
    }
}
```

For a better understanding I added the template, repository and associated services, I hope I can be as understandable as possible.
AbilitazioneRepository

```
public interface AbilitazioneRepository extends JpaRepository<Abilitazione, Long>{

    List<Abilitazione> findByDipendente(Dipendente dipendente);

}
```

For a better understanding I added the template, repository and associated services, I hope I can be as understandable as possible.

**AbilitazioneService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AbilitazioneService {

    @Autowired
    private AbilitazioneRepository abilitazioneRepository;

    public List<Abilitazione> findAll(){
        return abilitazioneRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Abilitazione abilitazione){
        abilitazioneRepository.save(abilitazione);
    }

    public List<Abilitazione> findAllAbilitazioniDi(Dipendente dipendente){
        return abilitazioneRepository.findByDipendente(dipendente);
    }
    //aggiunta ora
    public Abilitazione findAbilitazioneConId(Long id){
        return abilitazioneRepository.findOne(id);
    }
    //aggiunta ora per la cancellazione
    public void delete(Long id){
        abilitazioneRepository.delete(id);
    }

}
```

**IT.UNIROMA3.MODEL.DIPENDENTE CLASS**

```
    @Entity
public class Dipendente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Size(min=3,message="Inserisci un nome valido")
    private String nome;

    @Size(min=1,message="!")
    private String cognome;

    @NumberFormat
    private Integer cid;

    @Size(min=3,message="Inserisci un impianto valido")
    private String impianto;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dipendente", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Abilitazione> abilitazioni; 


    // plus getter and setter
```

Comment: ApplicationContext.xml

Comment: is this one an entity `Not an managed type: class it.uniroma3.model.Abilitazione `? share this class and its repository interface

Comment: @Barath I uploaded the requested information, I hope you can help me

Comment: share this class Dipendente dipendente ?

Comment: @Barath added the class Dipendente

Comment: you are missing couple of things in your entity definition `@JoinColumn` is also missing ideally Dipendente Id should be added as foreign key to Abilitazione entity apart from that below changes will resolve the above error

Comment: @Barath  this is not the problem ;(

Comment: share your project(github)

Comment: @Barath https://github.com/DeAngelisLuca/StackOverFlow

Answer (score 0):

you are missing couple of things :

1.Add @Entity and @Table to the entities(it is missing in the project shared) :

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Abilitazione 



@Entity
@Table
public class Dipendente
```

2.Replace the repository definition like below:

```
public interface AbilitazioneRepository extends JpaRepository<Abilitazione, Long>{

 Dipendente findByDipendenteId(Long dipendenteId);
}
```

3. Lot of dependency conflicts between spring data and hibernate dependencies in pom.xml.

Comment: oh is it i was able to replicate and fix it.

Comment: @LucaDeAngelis can you try hardcoding this value entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

Comment: github.com/DeAngelisLuca/StackOverFlow

Comment: news?   im disperate

Comment: @LucaDeAngelis too many mis configurations in your enitity classes and lot of dependency problems. its very difficult to narrow it down but still updated the depnedecnies to latest version and was able to resolve that problem .here is your modified project link that resolves this issue but some other entity mappings are yet to be resovled. https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Stackoverflow-issue

Comment: Thank you for having been very kind, is it not that you could solve the other mistakes? I would like to solve the dependency problem so that I can follow the right way for future project. I know it's asking a lot but I'm really disperated

Comment: updated the project it is working fine now https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Stackoverflow-issue. if you face table doesnt exists issue. create the tables appropriately first

Comment: check sqlscripts added for table creation . it is done using mysql . do the same for postgre and try

Comment: Thanks again for everything, you were really an exquisite person, if you go for Italy I will offer you a pizza;)

Comment: @Lucas cool. if it has helped you accept it as answer or upvote it.